# Hive - selecting the id for which the other field's value is ascending in consecutive timestamps

Tags: hive, timestamp, bigdata

I need to select the equipment_id for which the "Reading" is ascending in in consecutive Timestamps from the below Hive table 'Whether_report'.

```
station_id  equipment_id timpe_stamp Reading
 1              100       00:00:01    60
 2              100       00:00:02    61
 3              100       00:00:03    62
 4              100       00:00:04    60
 5              100       00:00:05    61
 .               .            .        .
 .               .            .        .
 16             114       00:00:11    66
 17             114       00:00:12    65
 .               .            .        .
 .               .            .        .
 .               .            .        .
 .               .            .        .
 29              112       00:00:23    71
 30              113       00:00:24    69
```

for example:- i need to select the euipment_id whose Reading is in ascending for five consecutive timestamps  (eg:- 60->61->62->63->64->65) and should not select the equipment_id for which the readings for consequent timestamps (eg:- 60->61->62->60->61). I am struggling to get the correct query.Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a loop to for your requirement:

```
     List<Integer> lis = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     int j=0, flag=1, width=0;

     lis.add(0, 60);
     lis.add(1, 61);
     lis.add(2, 61);
     lis.add(3, 60);
     lis.add(4, 61);
     lis.add(5, 62);
     lis.add(6, 64);
     lis.add(7, 66);
     lis.add(8, 68);



       Iterable<Integer> itr = lis;

       for(int i : itr)
       {
           if( j != 0) {

               if( width == 4)
                   break;

               if( i>j ) {
                   flag = 1;
                   width++;
               }
               else if( i<j && width != 4) {
                   flag = 0;
                   width = 0;
               }
           }

           System.out.println(i);
           j=i;
       }

       System.out.println("flag = "+flag+"width = "+ (width));

}
```

Output:
60
61
61
60
61
62
64
66
flag = 1 width = 4

I think if this can be plugged in the reducer class where the key is IntWritable equipment_id and value is Iterable IntWritable values and feed the values to this loop, assuming all time stamp values are unique.
Don't know if this is an optimal solution, considering the volume of data. Hope it helps !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to go to pig or MR. You are trying to find a sorted sub_sequence of length 5 in an bunch of readings, which probably cannot be achieved in a single query.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Spend some time on [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) then edit your answer.